# Vuejs dynamic require components

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a array with data and want to require vue js components from it, some=thing like:

```
var d = ["a.vue","b.vue"];
for(var k in d){
  let test = require('./'+d[k]);
  ...
}
```

It works fine but I get a warning in compile time because it tries to load only the './' - current root (without the d[k]). The components are loaded normal in the browser.

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
var test = resolve => require(['./a.vue'], resolve);
```

Comment: The various build tools depend on there being a literal value in the argument to `require`, as they need to replace that call with a reference to the contents of the file you reference. What do you need this for?

Comment: Hey Botje, Thanks for finding time to response. I'm building a custom cms where you can install various plugins. As they are installed by interface and our view side is powered by vue js, I need to create routes dynamically by using a json file with a list of plugins. Therefore, I need to get the array from json file and create  routes and components from it!

Comment: Have you looked at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components ? That would enable you to download and use components asynchronously, at least.